# Can you use setters and getters in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Below in my code example there is an example of a getter and setter is this the proper way of using them in Javascript?

**Question: Is this how to use a getter and setter in Javascript?**

Code:

```
<body>
<p>Object</p>

<script>
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
  this.model;
  this.year = year;
  this.miles = miles;

  this.setmodel = function (m) {
    if (do some checks here) {
       this.model = m;
    }
  };

  this.getmodel = function () {
    return model;
  };  

  this.toString = function () {
    return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
  };
}

Car.prototype.toAnotherString = function () {
   return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
};

var civic  = new Car( "Honda Civic", 2009, 20000 );
var mondeo = new Car( "Ford Mondeo", 2010, 5000 );

console.log( civic.toString() );
console.log( mondeo.toString() );
console.log( civic.toAnotherString() );
console.log( mondeo.toAnotherString() );

alert(civic.toString());
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your setter doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to call your setter and getter functions from somewhere. Consider making them self calling.

Comment: For heaven's sake, _why_?  What does this gain you in Javascript?

Comment: How do you make them self calling. Your right in Javascript it probably doesn't matter I am just trying to cover all of the basis in learning Javascript. From what I have read a person would not do this probably in real with a web page.

Comment: I know they are not called from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not correct. Your setter needs to... set the value, and your getter needs to get the value...

```
  this.setmodel = function (m) {
    this.model = m;
  };

  this.getmodel = function () {
    return this.model;
  };
```

Seems just a little pointless though since that property is directly available.

```
var civic  = new Car( "Honda Civic", 2009, 20000 );
civic.model = "Some model";
```

Setters and Getters are typically used for private variables that are purposely not publicly available, or for transforming data (such as your `toString` method)

Comment: +1 for "pointless".  This does not help encapsulate anything.  The underlying properties are no less exposed by adding g/setters.  They just add to the weight of the objects, or at least to their prototypes.

Comment: How can you make them private or is that even possible in javascript.

Comment: Is there really an reason in Javascript to have a getter or setter.

Comment: By declaring a variable inside the constructor and not setting it as a property on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, if you fix the setter to `this.model = m;`

and the getter to `return this.model;`

It isn't really necessary though. Unless you have special operations you need to perform or special validation to handle on incoming values, it just takes up extra space.